# hover effects n image icons using css

Tags: css

As i tried hover effects for image icons its working fine in my local server but when i deploy in online server on hover the color of the image is not changing immediately it is taking time to change the color of the icon for the first time.Thanks in Advance.

CSS:

```
.images1, .images2, .images3, .images4, .images5, .images6, .images7
 {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
       -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        transform: translateZ(0);
          box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
         -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
         -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
          -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
           transition-duration: 0.3s;
         -webkit-transition-property: transform;
          transition-property: transform;
          }

          .images1:hover, .images1:focus, .images1:active,
.images2:hover, .images2:focus, .images2:active,
         .images3:hover, .images3:focus, .images3:active,
        .images4:hover, .images4:focus, .images4:active, 
        .images5:hover, .images5:focus, .images5:active, 
       .images6:hover, .images6:focus, .images6:active, 
      .images7:hover, .images7:focus, .images7:active, 

     {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      transform: scale(1.1);
       }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How to add time for color changing on hover to image icons